# can't untar a complete directory using tar -cvpzf

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

Banging my head on this one...

I used `tar -cvpzf file.tar.gz` to compress a complete directory.

I move the file to another server and i try to decompress the directory where i have copied the archive. Can't make it work.

```
bash-3.2$ tar -xvpzf news.tar.gz .       
tar: gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: .: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your tar can't find gzip.  If you don't have gzip, you can't make a .gz file.  You should look for a gzip executable on your system.  What kind of system is it?

In the meantime, you could leave off the "z" and just transfer a .tar file.  It will be bigger, but at least you'll be able to move your data to the other server.

Comment: I'll be dam !
This is the right answer, gzip is not installed on this VPS.

Tks Marc for pointing me what i should have check first.

Answer (score 3):

Gzip was not installed on this server (VPS).
I should have check this part first instead of relying on assumption.

Lessons learn

Answer (score 3):

Install gzip, for example  ubuntu-

> apt-get install gzip

Then untar it -

> tar -xzf file.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

install **bzip2** and then it should be working. for example in debian/ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

or in gentoo

```
emerge bzip2
```

Answer (score 0):

if your directory name is "file/"
you create a tar.gz using

```
tar -cvzpf file.tar.gz file/
```

then untar it using

```
tar -xvf file.tar.gz
```

Comment: Tks for the suggestion, but it didn't help.
I have used the name of the directory i compress.

`bash-3.2$ tar -cvzpf news.tar.gz news_moving/
tar: gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
news_moving/`

I have created it also an empty directory in case of but still not good.

Comment: you must be in the parent directory of news_moving/ and have write permissions for creating a tar

Comment: You need tar xvfz to extract a .tar.gz (note the "z").  You can use tar xvf to extract a .tar file.  Note that the "-" is optional.

Comment: @MarkAdler: tar 1.21 (or around that version) autodetects compression and does not need -z/etc. anymore. While the - is optional, it is better to use it, since the old option format is just plain awkward and error-prone.

Comment: You're correct -- I didn't know until I just tried it that tar (at least GNU tar) has a compression autodetect.  Also from decades of habit, I never use the "-", since there was a time it didn't work.  For backward compatibility with scripts, I'm sure that no "-" will always work.

Comment: Well, that new habit didn't last long.  I ran into a GNU tar version 1.14 on my hosting service on which leaving off the "z" doesn't work, so I'll go back to including the "z" when unpacking a tar.gz.