# Script don't extract tar

Tags: linux, shell

I have this script shell, it extract and install libpcap library

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/src
wget=/usr/bin/wget
tar=/bin/tar

echo "###############"
echo "INSTALL LIBPCAP"
echo "###############"
$tar -xvf libpcap-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd libpcap-1.3.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

When I execute it , I have this error

```
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/bin/tar: Child returned status 2
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./install.sh: 14: cd: can't cd to libpcap-1.3.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't untar a complete directory using tar -cvpzf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749466/cant-untar-a-complete-directory-using-tar-cvpzf)

Comment: seems like gzip is missing on your system or sh cannot find it. Check if gzip exists, if yes, check if its in the search path of SH (you could possible "echo $PATH" in your script and see if the folder where gzip is located is in the path)

Comment: this the content of $PATH /root/.embulk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed PATH to /usr/src so when tar tries to exec gzip, it cannot find it because it only looks in /usr/src.  You'll need to add the location of gzip to PATH (and the location of every tool that the configure script is going to call, as well as make), or call it explicitly instead of letting tar call it, or (best choice), don't modify PATH.  If you insist on changing PATH, try `PATH=/usr/src:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` or `PATH=/usr/src:$PATH`, but really it's best to leave it alone and really odd to put a directory named `src` into it.

Comment: if I don't use PATH, the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you want `/usr/src` added to `PATH` variable then the better approach will be as

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/src"
```

To make your script run from any directory path use a separate variable which holds the absolute path of the source file path like `file_path` variable which is used in the below script.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="$PATH:/usr/src"
wget=/usr/bin/wget
tar=/bin/tar
file_path="/path/to/source-files"

echo "###############"
echo "INSTALL LIBPCAP"
echo "###############"
$tar -xvf $file_path/libpcap-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd $file_path/libpcap-1.3.0
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with gzipped tar, you should explicitly pass the option `-z`, so your code should be something like:

$tar -x**z**vf libpcap-1.3.0.tar.gz